# how to execute a command as string in echo

Tags: batch-file

I need the hostname of windows to be written into text file as "hostname=google-871"

here google-871 is the hostname of the machine.

Below is the script i have tried

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET MACHINE_NAME=%%i
echo hostname=%MACHINE_NAME%>"D:\temp\hostname.txt"
```

The error was:

C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

Actual result:

google-871

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `(Echo(|Set /P "=Hostname="&Hostname)>"D:\temp\hostname.txt"`

Comment: @LogeshElangovan I have never seen a Windows computer having multiple host names, i.e. multiple computer names. However a single command line for usage in batch file would be: `@(for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\system32\hostname.exe 2^>nul') do @echo hostname=%%I)>"D:\temp\hostname.txt"` The `for /F` options `delims=` and `eol=` define an empty list of string delimiters and no end of line character to really get entire line output by `hostname` assigned to loop variable `I` output with additional text by `echo` which is redirected into file `D:\temp\hostname.txt` by `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname is already a system variable set at `%computername%` - so all you need to do is:

```
(echo hostname=%computername%)>"D:\temp\hostname.txt"
```

If you have a list of hostnames or needed something more specific, just leave a comment or edit your question with what specific outcome you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mael, if the machine has n host names how can we approach?

Comment: are you saying the machine has multiple hostnames? or you have multiple hostnames you'd like to loop through in a text file or something?

Comment: @LogeshElangovan, how does a machine with multiple hostnames identify itself on the network?